# What metal-printing methods exist to create this style of finish?

Tags: enclosure

I have an old panel faceplate (circa 2000) that I am trying to create a replacement for. It appears that the two commonly available methods to put graphics on a metal faceplate are UV printing and engraving. My best guess is that this panel started with a plain sheet of aluminum and then had an image UV printed onto it (including the black background).

From the pictures, can anyone determine if this is correct or if another method was used? My goal is for the new faceplate to be as close to the original as possible.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6h8t.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an Electrical Engineering question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I wondered about that too, but [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/306713/panel-mounting-an-lcd-screen-in-a-hobby-project) question seems to set the precedent that it is acceptable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. As well as [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43012/fabricating-control-panels) one and numerous others

Comment: Well, that's why we have a voting system here... And not a precedent based one.

Comment: While I agree this is probably off topic, I recall reading suggestions of using a PCB fab for this, with either silkscreen or even soldermask for the art.  I think I even read of someone using an aluminum process (normally used for thermal properties with things like power hungry LEDs)

Comment: the color of the background is not black

Comment: @jsotola What color would you call it? Dark gray?

Comment: Probably a Tampo plate. http://www.tampo.co.uk/ or service by a company like https://pad-print.co.uk/

Comment: Designing a good looking enclosure is the most annoying part of DIY electronics, so this is on-topic IMO...

Comment: it is gray with a slight brown tint ... i examined the colors in the picture using AutoIt Window Info app (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) .... the last picture shows the RGB values for the lettering to be like 0xE0E0E0 and the gray to be 0x5B5555 ... so the lettering is a shade of white(no color tint) and the background is below 50% gray with a touch of red (this assumes that the illumination is white)

Comment: you can take the panel to a paint shop that has a computerized paint chip matching machine.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, but I don't think this is utterly off-topic. This site is about electronics design, not *circuit* design. I.e. we also consider all the industrial steps needed to design and manufacture an electronic *product*. Otherwise also, say, questions about potting compounds would be off-topic (too much chemistry?!?).

Comment: @LorenzoDonati You don't have to be sorry, neither I don't. We both are entitled to have an opinion. I would put it in the same pile with questions about selecting a saw to cut a wooden box for one's electronic project enclosure....

Comment: Looks like plain old silk screen printing to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While this isn't an electronics question in itself, it is a problem faced by many of us when finishing off an electronics project in an attempt to create a professional finish.

It is most likely done by a screen-printing process. These are low-cost for one-off or low quantity production runs.

[image]

*Figure 1. A screen-print jig. Source: [Guitar Fool](http://guitarfool.com/Silkscreen.html).*

The linked article author sends his artwork out to have the screen created. He then fastens it into his jig, presses it down on the panel and squeegee's the ink through.

If you weren't trying to get an exact colour match I would recommend that you have the panel made. Many of the PCB manufacturers make front panels too as the processes are quite similar: silk screen (solder and component designations) and drilling and routing. They can generally offer aluminium and plastics.

[image]

*Figure 2. [Panel-Pool](https://www.panel-pool.com/fpuk/index.html) are one such company, in Europe, at least.*

Panels can be "pooled" (assorted customers' jobs run through on one common panel before final cut-off) just as PCBs are. I used this company, oddly enough, for a mechanical part that had a fine grid of small (< 1 mm) holes. The task had been declined by the machine shops in my area. The laser cutting shops said they couldn't do it either due to the lead-in generated by the standard laser equipment. The PCB shops, on the other hand, do small holes all the time.

Comment: Is the result scratch proof?

Comment: That's going to depend on the paint used. Look it up. I would expect it to be reasonably tough - think of guitar amplifier, mixer desk, etc.

Comment: The one thing that makes me think it is not silk screen is the various levels of grayscale present in the graphics (shadow behind "EIS" text)

Comment: Perhaps useful to add that the black background was likely obtained by powder coating the part before being screen printed.

Comment: @user8908459 If you look closely at the “shadow”, you’ll see that it is actually a half-tone, a grid pattern of white lines that, at a distance, looks like grey. As long as the silk screen is fine enough resolution, it can easily produce this.

Comment: Exactly. Looks like it was powder coated first.

Comment: Another approach I have used is to use a clear plastic front panel and silk-screen the white on the back, then cover that with a black or coloured coat, with openings for leds and displays to be seen through. It makes for a nice shiny face plate, with less holes, and the text will never wear off. It does tend to get scratched over time though.

Comment: So the general consensus is powder coated and silkscreen?

Comment: Any chance it might be anodized instead of powder coated? From what I've read, powder cost is hard to silkscreen on.

Comment: anodized aluminium shows the underlying metal through the tint (as far as i have seen in the past)  ... the picture shows the metal that is covered by other material

Comment: what about using a blank PCB (or one that has the lettering etched) and have it silk screened ... i have an Arduino Uno that is silk screened on the back and the printing appears to be quite tough ... https://www.circuitspecialists.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/UNO-back_Arduino.jpg

Comment: If it's aluminium underneath, it's never going to be scratchproof, alas! Powder is one of the more durable options for surfacing though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the original manufacturer and get more details. It's actually a aluminum subpanel with a lexan overlay on top.